# How to replace arbitrary values of a variable with sequential values?

Tags: foreach, stata

<For example:
a variable has values     1 2 3 5 10 11 12 13 14 20 21 ....
I want to replace it with 1 2 3 4 5  6  7  8  9  10 11.....
I was using this command but is not giving, the desired results:
old variable=district
I want to replace value with the correct sequential values>

```
levelsof district, local(district_new)
foreach i in `district_new'{
    replace district= mod(_n-1,707)+1
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not fully sure what you trying to do, but is this a solution to what you are trying to do:

```
sort district
replace district = _n
```

This will replace the values in district with 1 for the lowest current value, 2 for the second lowest value etc. This might not be a good solution if your variable may have duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @TheIceBear but more can be said that won't fit easily into comments.

The particular code posted boils down to a single statement repeated

```
replace district = mod(_n-1,707) + 1
```

as that action is repeated regardless of the values of `district`. In a dataset with 707 or fewer observations, that in turn would be equivalent to

```
replace district = _n
```

as @TheIceBear points out. If there were duplicate observations on any district, this would definitely be a bad idea, and something like

```
egen newid = group(district), label
```

would be a better idea. For more, see https://www.stata.com/support/faqs/data-management/creating-group-identifiers/

Comment: yes, the approach by @TheIceBear works only of there are no duplicates. This can be avoided by doing preserve-drop duplicates-store tempfile-restore-merge with tempfile sequence, but egen is much cleaner.